# Is it possible to enforce referential integrity when a foreign key is refernced twice in the same table?

Tags: ms-access-2007

So here is the crux of my problem. I have an entity named "Person" with a primary key personid. I have an entity called "Permission Slip" that requires the personid of the student and personid of the parent. In the "Permission Slip" entity I have foreign key personid to represent the student and then a foreign parentid (also a personid) to represent the parent. When I try to enforce referential integrity I keep getting and error. Any idea of why this is?

Answer (score 0):

In the relations windows, pull in table Person twice.

Then, create a relation between Student and the first Person table and a relation between Parent and the second Person table.